# Translating an entire column in excel and pasting results in the next column

Tags: excel, vba

Translating an entire column in excel and pasting results in the next column.My code is as follows:

```
Sub test()
Dim s, r As Range, l As String

For Each s In Range("A2:A3").Cells
        l = s
        **Range("B2:B3").Cells = translate_using_vba(s, l)**

     Next s

End Sub


Public Function translate_using_vba(str, l) As String
' Tools Refrence Select Microsoft internet Control
    Dim IE As Object, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim inputstring As String, outputstring As String, text_to_convert As String, result_data As String, CLEAN_DATA
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    '   TO CHOOSE INPUT LANGUAGE
    inputstring = "auto"
    '   TO CHOOSE OUTPUT LANGUAGE
    outputstring = "en"

    text_to_convert = str
    'open website
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "http://translate.google.com/#" & inputstring & "/" &outputstring & "/" & text_to_convert
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    CLEAN_DATA = Split(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(IE.Document.getElementById("result_box").innerHTML, "</SPAN>", ""), "<")

    For j = LBound(CLEAN_DATA) To UBound(CLEAN_DATA)
        result_data = result_data & Right(CLEAN_DATA(j), Len(CLEAN_DATA(j)) - InStr(CLEAN_DATA(j), ">"))
    Next   

    IE.Quit
    translate_using_vba = result_data


End Function
```

Question: It works fine but my result in column B is overwritten each time. How can I can store B2 value first and then move to B3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set r = Range("B2") ' Initial (starting) cell
For Each s In Range("A2:A3").Cells
    l = s
    r.value = translate_using_vba(s, l)
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0) 'Next row
Next s
```

Comment: One question for improvement- When the data in the cell is large with lot of spaces and ========, there is a run time error: Application-defined or object- defined error at line "r.Value = translate_using_vba(s, l)". Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Well, debug your code by single-stepping through it and make use of the Immediate window to find out why